# Remove duplicate string from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following dynamically generated arrays:

```
,<div id="layer0" style="left: 470px; top: 286px;">Some Text</div>
,<div id="layer0" style="font-size: 68px; left: 70px; top: 286px; ">SomeText</div>
,<div id="layer1" style="font-size: 18px; left: 60px; top: 286px; ">SomeText</div>
,<div id="layer2" style="font-size: 18px; left: 50px; top: 286px; ">SomeText</div>
```

The first 2 entries are not exactly duplicates but have the same `id="layer0"`. The second one is different because it has a CSS font-size propriety.

How can I remove the first any from this array that has a duplicate `id` but may differ in the exact form?

The arrays are combined together trough:

```
var allcode = $.merge([oldarray],[newarray])
```

Where in `oldarray` are some duplicates I need to get rid of.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be ahead to more carefully combine the arrays, rather than mash them together and clean up later.

```
function matchId(htmlstring){
    var match = htmlstring.match( new RegExp(/id=\"([^\"]+)\"/i) ); 
    if (match && match[1]) {
        return match[1];
    }
    return '';
}

for (var j=0; j < oldarray.length; j++) {

    var exists = false;

    for (var k=0; k < newarray.length; k++) {

        var newId = matchId(newarray[k]);
        var oldId = matchId(oldarray[j]);

        if (newId == oldId) {
            // element already exists.
            exists=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!exists) {
        newarray.push( oldarray[j] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with carefully combining.  But I think it's an array of HTML strings, so some parsing is required before comparing id properties.

Comment: Thanx, in my code this duplicate all the #IDs. Please let me check it to see where I do it wrong.

Comment: I get some "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of null". Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: the first method assumes `htmlstring` is a valid string. you can add this line to the top of the match method: `if(!htmlstring){return;}`